# Basic Java Fundamentals

Tags: java

Attempting to call a method that's in another object

```
public Shred(Path dir, int id){
        filename = dir.resolve(id+".png").toString();
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Using this loop

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
            allShreds = allShreds + Shred(dir,i);
        }
```

However the Shred method is not able to be found using my code

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you write the full code so we can know why `Shred` method was not found. Most probably you forgot to import, maybe...

Comment: Nobody is explaining how, but the way you identify a constructor method is that it has no return type, and the method name is the same as the class name.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a **constructor** not a method. And the constructor will return a `Shred`. It isn't clear what `allShreds` is, but assuming it's a `String` you could do

```
allShreds = allShreds + new Shed(dir,i).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Shred(Path dir, int id) is a constructor.
To access constructor method, you have to use it with new keyword as below:
allShreds = allShreds + new Shred(dir,i);

Also, the + operator wont work on Shread class object as used in below code:
allShreds = allShreds + Shred(dir,i);